# I have table layout in which i am trying to add button dynamically and i want to reduce size of button i am trying to do so but size is not changing

Tags: android

I have write this method to add button in table layout dynamically 
m trying to set height and width to each button when  create  button but some how its not working

```
 private TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams;
    rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rowParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

> in above code i am setting row parameter

```
 public void addButton_with_filter(final Test test,
            TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams, Activity context) {

        ArrayList<Integer> filteredquestionno;
        TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(context);
        LinearLayout filterlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterlayout);
        filterlayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        filteredquestionno = getLayoutFilteredQuestionNumber(test
                .getQuestions());

        int size = filteredquestionno.size();
        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "NO QUSTION IS AVAILABLE OF THIS FILTER TYPE !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        int norows = (size / 5) + 1;
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < norows; i++) {
                TableRow currentRow = new TableRow(FilterActivity.this);

                while (j < 5 && k < size) {
                    j++;
                    Button qindex = new Button(FilterActivity.this);
                    qindex.setWidth(5);/*width*/
                    qindex.setHeight(5);/*height*/
                    if (submited == true) {
                        if (test.getQuestionAtIndex(filteredquestionno.get(k))
                                .isCorrectlyAnswered()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_answer);
                        } else if (test.getQuestionAtIndex(
                                filteredquestionno.get(k)).isAttempted()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);
                        } else if (test.getQuestionAtIndex(
                                filteredquestionno.get(k)).isSkipped()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.skipped_answer);
                        } else if (!test.getQuestionAtIndex(
                                filteredquestionno.get(k)).isAttempted()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unattempted_question);
                        }
                    } else if (submited == false) {
                        if (test.getQuestionAtIndex(filteredquestionno.get(k))
                                .isAttempted()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);
                        } else if (test.getQuestionAtIndex(
                                filteredquestionno.get(k)).isSkipped()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.skipped_answer);
                        } else if (!test.getQuestionAtIndex(
                                filteredquestionno.get(k)).isAttempted()) {
                            qindex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unattempted_question);
                        }
                    }

                    qindex.setText(" " + (filteredquestionno.get(k) + 1));
                    k++;

                    qindex.setId(k);
                    qindex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Button b = (Button) v;
                            String text = (String) b.getText();
                            String t = text.trim();
                            int questionindex = Integer.parseInt(t);
                            if (type == 0) {
                                test.setLastQuestionAttempted(questionindex - 1);
                                FilterActivity.this.finish();
                            } else if (type == 1) {
                                test.setLastQuestionAttempted(questionindex - 1);
                                FilterActivity.this.finish();
                            }

                        }
                    });





                    currentRow.addView(qindex, rowParams);
                }
                j = 0;
                tl.addView(currentRow);

            }
            filterlayout.addView(tl);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
Button qindex = new Button(FilterActivity.this);
qindex.setWidth(5);/*width*/
qindex.setHeight(5);/*
```

set layout params to button:

```
LayoutParams lp= new LayaoutParams(5,5); // width,height
qindex.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

If you get classCastException, try:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp= new TableLayout.LayaoutParams(5,5); // width,height
qindex.setLayoutParams(lp);
```